# Wasabi (peas) brussel sprouts?

Tags: food-preservation, food-processing, wasabi, brussels-sprouts, snacks

I was wondering how successfully the formula of wasabi peas can be applied to other green vegetables?

I'm familiar with them as a snack in some pubs in England, the peas become hard and crunchy, and 'spicy' in the same way as horseradish is, partly because wasabi is usually made with horseradish.

Comment: Just something to share with you: [Harvest Snaps Snapea Crisps Wasabi Ranch](http://www.amazon.com/Harvest-Snaps-Snapea-Crisps-Wasabi/dp/B00CMQE1QY/ref=sr_1_2?s=grocery&ie=UTF8&qid=1431112980&sr=1-2&keywords=snapea+crisps). Fabulous IMO. Great on salads instead of croutons.

Comment: Your title specifically mentions brussels sprouts, but your question doesn't. You may want to clarify so you get better answers. Sprouts in particular could be a challenge because of their size, but there may be other green veg that people have successfully converted into spicy-bar-snack form.

Comment: I think that brussel sprouts would be particularly interesting, I don't know how the change in texture is achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once attempted to make Brussel Sprout Chips (in much the same way you can make Kale chips)... That worked... now if you can make a wasabi sauce/dressing or sprinkle freshly grated Wasabi so it bakes onto the sprout leaves you may have something...

- Preheat the oven to moderate oven 180°C/350°F.
- Remove the leaves of the brussels sprouts. This is tedious work, but it can be done. You want as many leaves as possible, and you may need to keep cutting away the stem as you get deeper into the sprout.
- Place the leaves on a baking sheet and drizzle generously with olive oil, tossing to coat. Sprinkle with the sea salt/wasabi/whatever dry flavours.
- Bake, turning every 5 to 7 minutes, until browned and crunchy, almost burnt, but not burnt.